# How to display the correct tooltip text while mapping over a list?

Tags: reactjs

I am looping over a list and I want to add tooltip text according to the labels.
I am using react-bootstrap and created a reusable component called `<LinkWithTooltip />`

I am using ternary if item.label==="a" ? "text a" : "text b"

But I dont think this is a good way.

Here is the code

```
networkingStatics: [
        { label: 'Total Connections Made', value: 0 },
        { label: 'Average Connections Per Attendee', value: 0 },
        { label: 'Total Messages Sent', value: 'Coming Soon' },
        { label: 'Total Meetings', value: 'Coming Soon' },
        { label: 'Total Matches', value: 0 },
      ],
      return (
          <Row>
           {networkingStatics.map((item) => (
             <LinkWithTooltip tooltip= {item.label==="" ? "" : "" >
               <label className="box-lable">{item.label}</label>
                <span>{item.value}</span>
             </LinkWithTooltip>
```

**Note:**
Tooltip text is different to the ones mentioned in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

& the following code will work for you

```
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

return (
    <div>
      {networkingStatics.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <label className="box-lable" data-tip={item.label} >{item.label}</label>
          <span data-tip={item.value} >{item.value}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <ReactTooltip />
    </div>
  );
```

You can check this snippet of code https://react-qyhikx.stackblitz.io

Comment: Hey.
I forgot to mention tooltip text is different to the ones mentioned in the label.

Comment: In that case. you'll need to pass one more property to the object 'networkingStatics' & use it as 'data-tip={item.newProperty}'